# Seletor CSS para tabelas

Tags: css, css3

Estou fazendo uma refatoração em um código e tem um regra CSS que está mudando o display de todas tabelas. Uma tabela em específico está visualmente quebrada por conta dessa alteração. Como ainda não vi todo o código, temo que se eu sobrescrever esta regra possa quebrar outras estruturas que são dependentes dela. Existe algum seletor CSS que eu consiga dizer: *"Pegue todas as tabelas exceto as com classe `.tabela-isolada`"* ?

```
table, thead, tbody, th, td, tr { 
    display: block; 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode usar o pseudo-seletor `:not` assim:

```
:not(.tabela-isolada)
```

Como tem vários estilos, e quer excluir pela tabela, vai ficar um pouco extenso:

```
table:not(.tabela-isolada),
:not(.tabela-isolada) > thead,
:not(.tabela-isolada) > tbody,
:not(.tabela-isolada) > * > th,
:not(.tabela-isolada) > * > td,
:not(.tabela-isolada) > * > tr {
    display: block;
}
```

[Referência na MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anot) - note pela MDN, que o suporte desse seletor não é amplo, principalmente se falando de IE

Comment: +1 Ficaria mais fácil visualizar se houvesse quebra de linha nas vírgulas :)

Comment: @LeandroAmorim: também acho, editei a resposta. =D

Answer (score 2):

**Acho que o que você quer seja isso:**

```css
table, thead, tbody, th, td, tr:not('.tabela-isolada') { 
    display: block; 
}
```

`:not()` é uma `pseudo-class` de negação.

> Obs: Não é suportada por todos os browsers, como especificado no [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anot)

**Referências:**

- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anot)
- [css-tricks](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/not/)

Answer (score 2):

Vamos por partes, esse código

```
table, thead, tbody, th, td, tr { 
    display: block; 
}
```

está colocando diplay block em todos esses elementos:

> `table`
>   `thead`
>   `tbody`
>   `th`
>   `td`
>   `tr`

Usando o padrão do **[w3](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#table-display)** para ter o efeito "original" da tabela você teria que fazer algo assim:

```
table.tabela-isolada { display: table !important; }
table.tabela-isolada tr { display: table-row !important; }
table.tabela-isolada thead { display: table-header-group !important; }
table.tabela-isolada tbody { display: table-row-group !important; }
table.tabela-isolada tfoot { display: table-footer-group !important; }
table.tabela-isolada col { display: table-column !important; }
table.tabela-isolada colgroup { display: table-column-group !important; }
table.tabela-isolada td,
table.tabela-isolada th { display: table-cell !important; }
table.tabela-isolada caption { display: table-caption !important; }
```

E para não ter problemas de sobrescrita de propriedade insira esse CSS posterior ao que coloca o `display: block` .

Comment: +1 pela solução que funciona em browsers antigos.