# Como não selecionar um elemento em css?

Tags: css, html5

Eu quero selecionar todos os elementos  que estão dentro de uma div, mas tem um  em específico que eu não quero que seja selecionado.

Como posso fazer essa "desceleção"?

Comment: Amigo existem várias formas para isso, se vc não colocar pelo menos o HTML da situação que vc tem ai fica difícil de te responder. Por favor edite a pergunta e coloque o código, mesmo que esse código seja um exemplo prático mais perto do que vc tem.

Comment: Coloque na pergunta um exemplo de código e o que vc não deseja que seja selecionado.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Seletor CSS para tabelas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/10918/seletor-css-para-tabelas)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hugo, o ideal seria você colocar o código em sua pergunta para que a mesma possa ser respondida.

Existem muitas maneiras de se atingir o efeito desejado.

Segue abaixo uma forma de fazer isso.

```css
p:not(.no-bg) {
   background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div>
      <p>parágrafo 1</p>
      <p>parágrafo 2</p>
      <p>parágrafo 3</p>
      <p>parágrafo 4</p>
      <p class="no-bg">parágrafo 5</p>
      <p>parágrafo 6</p>
      <p>parágrafo 7</p>
      <p>parágrafo 8</p>
      <p>parágrafo 9</p>
      <p>parágrafo 10</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

No código acima foi aplicado um background vermelho em todos os parágrafos da **div**. Para isso, foi criado uma regra **CSS** para ser aplicada aos elementos "**P**". Nesta regra, também foi adicionado o seletor "**:Not**", para que no elemento com a classe "**no-bg**" não fosse aplicada a regra de background.

Acredito que com esse exemplo, você possa adaptar o código para a sua necessidade, lembrando que, existem muitas outras formas de se fazer isso além a citada acima.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar o [not](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/:not)

Vou dar um exemplo abaixo:

```css
.lista *:not(:nth-child(2)) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="lista">
  <li>Um</li>
  <li>Dois</li>
  <li>Três</li>
</ul>
```

O :not ele não irá aplicar o style no elemento que eu selecionei, que no caso é a segunda `li`, pegando com `nth-child(2)`